# What is the meaning of taking a slice on a Get-Content that uses -ReadCount?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to understand the meaning and effect of using -ReadCount on Get-Content. Why does [3..5] not produce and array of (3, 4, 5)? What does this notation mean?

```
PS C:\src\t> (1..40) | Set-Content numbers.txt
PS C:\src\t> (Get-Content .\numbers.txt -ReadCount 5)[3..5]
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
PS C:\src\t> (Get-Content .\numbers.txt -ReadCount 5)[3..4]
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `-ReadCount` has no effect on how many lines are passed through the pipeline *overall*.
- Instead, it determines how many lines are passed *at a time*, as an *array*; in other words: it is a *chunking mechanism*.

Therefore, with `-ReadCount 5`, arrays of 5 lines at a time are passed through the pipeline, and `[3..5]` therefore selects the 4th array through the 6th array, i.e., 3 5-element arrays; since they're just output to the *screen*, these 3 arrays *appear* to be a flat array, but they're not.

For instance, to get the 2nd array among the 5-element output arrays, use:

```
PS> (Get-Content .\numbers.txt -ReadCount 5)[1]
6
7
8
9
10
```

Note that `-ReadCount 0` would pass *all* input lines as a *single* `[object[]]` array through the pipeline.